# Is a Laskerian ring coherent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, coherent-sheaves

A commutative ring $R$ with identity is said to be coherent if every f.g. ideal of $R$ is f.p. We know that any noetherian ring is coherent. A Laskerian ring is a ring in which every ideal has a primary decomposition. Now, Is any  Laskerian ring  coherent?

Answer (score 3):

Even strongly Laskerian rings are not necessarily coherent.

By a theorem of Radu strongly Laskerian coherent rings are Noetherian, and there are examples of strongly Laskerian rings which are not Noetherian.